# eclipse create team project for tfs

Tags: team-explorer-everywhere

I'm trying to create a TFS project in a collection using Eclipse Kepler. It seems like I couldn't find a way to create it.

Thus when working on a new project, I am trying to upload the code as well as create a TFS project to see it on the web interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a Team Project from Team Explorer Everywhere.  You will need to create a Team Project from Visual Studio.  After the project is created, you can access it from Team Explorer Everywhere in Eclipse.

Comment: alright thanks, I wonder why Ms doesn't want to be compatible with other tools.

Comment: Creating a Team Project involves creating things like Sharepoint sites and SQL Server Reporting.  This is very difficult for us to do on all the platforms that TEE is supported, like AIX or Solaris.

Comment: Sure, what about starting with Windows OS?

Comment: For Windows, that functionality is available in the normal Team Explorer.  I regret that you have to use two tools at the moment; we're working on improving this for a future release.